# Use zlib inflate() in c++ to decompress via PHP ZLIB_ENCODING_RAW encoded data

Tags: php, c++, c, zlib

When I compress a string in `PHP` with encoding `ZLIB_ENCODING_DEFLATE` and output the hex data, I can convert this back to the original string using `zlib` `deflate()` in a c++ project.

Per the example here ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zlib-encode.php ) :

```
<?php
$str = 'hello world';
$enc = zlib_encode($str, ZLIB_ENCODING_DEFLATE);
echo bin2hex($enc);
?>
```

in c++, after having converted the hex string to binary data first: (simplified code)

```
z_stream d_stream;

d_stream.zalloc = (alloc_func)0 ;
d_stream.zfree  = (free_func)0 ;
d_stream.opaque = (voidpf)0 

d_stream.next_in  = InBuffer ;
d_stream.avail_in = InBufferLen ;
d_stream.next_out = OutBuffer ;
d_stream.avail_out = OutBufferLen ;

int err = inflateInit(&d_stream) ;

while (err == Z_OK)
    err = inflate(&d_stream, Z_NO_FLUSH);

err = inflateEnd(&d_stream);
```

`OutBuffer` contains "hello world" again

I was wondering if `zlib` `inflate()` also decompresses the via `PHP` generated `zlib_encode($str, ZLIB_ENCODING_RAW);` raw data ?

From the zlib documentation I think not:

> The deflate compression method (**the only one supported in this
> version**).
>
> #define Z_DEFLATED   8

But `PHP`'s function name `zlib_encode()` and define `ZLIB_ENCODING_RAW` seem to suggest `zlib` does support it ?  If so what function and/or parameters do I use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP designations are (as usual) confusing. I will assume that `ZLIB_ENCODING_RAW` means raw deflate data (per RFC 1951), and it appears that `ZLIB_ENCODING_DEFLATE` actually means zlib-wrapped deflate data (per RFC 1950).

If that's correct, they should have called them `ZLIB_ENCODING_DEFLATE` and `ZLIB_ENCODING_ZLIB`, respectively. But I digress.

You can decode raw deflate data with the zlib library by using `inflateInit2()` instead of `inflateInit()`, and giving `-15` as the second argument.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly.  The (via `PHP`) `RAW` compressed data is essentially the same as the `DEFLATE` compressed data, except that it misses 2 bytes at the start, 4 bytes at the end and the last two bytes (before the 4-bytes-tail) are different as well.

Comment: Your 'assumption' re designation and suggestion as to how the defines *should* have been named is spot on. PHP's `RAW` is indeed 'raw' DEFLATE without headers and CRC, and PHP's `DEFLATE` is indeed the ZLIB variant (headers and crc).

Comment: PS ignore my comment about the 2 bytes being different (that was a wrong observation)